# Running the SUBSTRING_INDEX query on a column

Tags: mysql, join

I have this column called `location` in a table called `raw_data`. Each row have lots of varchar data separated by `[, ]`. Examples

Row 1 `dusseldorf, kjsbdfygs4, Germany`

Row 2 `768768745h, kiev, Ukraine`

Row 3 `%%%%666, Accra, Ghana`

Yes some make no sense. Im trying to select the `last part` of the string which is the `country` and display it.
I tried using the `substring index` query and understand how it works but cant seem to understand how to apply it to a column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use as per below-

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(my_column,',',-1) FROM raw_data;
```

Note: If you need 1st part then use only 1 instead of -1.

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(location ,',',2);
```

go to below link for explanation

http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring_index-function.php